# Including magento js files in custom module layout file - magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, extensions, requirejs

I'm new to Magento. I want to include the following js files in my custom module's layout file in the following location.

> app/code/MyVendor/MyModule/view/adminhtml/layout/mymodule_template_custom.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <title>
        My Module Custom Page
    </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024"/>
    <css src="MyVendor_MyModule::css/custom.css"/>
    <link src="Magento_Sales::order/giftoptions_tooltip.js"/>
    <link src="Magento_ConfigurableProduct::js/configurable.js"/>
    <link src="Magento_Sales::order/create/scripts.js"/>
    <link src="Magento_Catalog::catalog/product/composite/configure.js"/>
    <link src="Magento_Sales::order/create/giftmessage.js"/>
</head>
```

But when I take "view page source" I'm unable to see the same js files included.

Kindly help me

Thanks In Advance

Comment: please show your js file in folder. where you have keep all js file?

Comment: have you ran the `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`?

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to add js before js file in your xml file.

Instead of
 `<link src="Magento_Sales::order/create/giftmessage.js"/>`

you have to keep

```
<link src="Magento_Sales::js/order/create/giftmessage.js"/>
```

Full js code,

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <title>
        My Module Custom Page
    </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024"/>
    <css src="MyVendor_MyModule::css/custom.css"/>
    <link src="Magento_Sales::js/order/giftoptions_tooltip.js"/>
    <link src="Magento_ConfigurableProduct::js/configurable.js"/>
    <link src="Magento_Sales::js/order/create/scripts.js"/>
    <link src="Magento_Catalog::js/catalog/product/composite/configure.js"/>
    <link src="Magento_Sales::js/order/create/giftmessage.js"/>
</head>
```

Run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command.